# DJANGO type eror module object is not callable

Tags: django

File "/home/mushfiqul/Mushfiqul/django_pro/simplesocial/posts/views.py", line 48, in form_valid
    self.object.save()
  File "/home/mushfiqul/Mushfiqul/django_pro/simplesocial/posts/models.py", line 24, in save
    self.message_html = misaka(self.message)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.user = self.request.user
            self.object.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: The error is in `self.message_html = misaka(self.message)`... Here `misaka` is a *module*, not a *function*.

Comment: Thanks. I change is to    self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)       and it worked

Answer (score 0):

the own misaka is not a callable function, you should use it as below in this situation:

```
# do something
self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
# do something
```